# Has Comb Sort been proven correct? Can it be?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, proof, correctness

I've been doing some research on Comb Sort and I'm trying to figure out whether the algorithm has been proven correct. However, I can't seem to find a great deal of documentation on the algorithm. It's a very simple algorithm, though--basically a variant of Bubble Sort--and I'm guessing the proof isn't complicated. Does anyone have ideas about where I can find more info on this, or thoughts about how to prove it from scratch?

For those unfamiliar with Comb Sort, you can find the pseudo code on the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combsort).

Comment: what do you mean, proven correct?

Comment: The final pass when `gap==1` is equivalent to a bubble sort. If bubble sort is correct then so is Comb sort.

Comment: Ah good point. So I guess all you have to do is prove that the gap variable in the loop eventually reaches 1.

Comment: @Blastfurnace However bubble sort takes O(n^2) to sort, just because one pass is similar to bubble sort's one pass, doesn't mean that the whole algorithm is correct.

Comment: @PrathikRajendranM Perhaps I should have said "stage" instead of "pass". The fact remains that when `gap` becomes 1 Comb sort is equivalent to a bubble sort.

Comment: @Blastfurnace true. stage makes it more appropriate. since in comb sort at `gap == 1` if a switch is made, it loops again.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the pseudocode from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_sort#Pseudocode):

```js
function combsort(array input) is
    gap := input.size
    shrink := 1.3
    sorted := false

    loop while sorted = false
        gap := floor(gap / shrink)
        if gap ≤ 1 then
            gap := 1
            sorted := true
        end if

        i := 0
        loop while i + gap < input.size
            if input[i] > input[i+gap] then
                swap(input[i], input[i+gap])
                sorted := false
            end if

            i := i + 1
         end loop
     end loop
end function
```

The main loop is `while sorted = false`, and there no `break` statements stopping the loop early, which is very helpful for the proof: if this loop ever terminates, it must be the case that `sorted = true`. So really, we only have to show two things: firstly that the loop does terminate, and secondly that if `sorted = true` at the end of the loop then the array actually is sorted.

- The loop terminates because each time `sorted` is still `false` at the end of an iteration, either `gap` gets smaller, or `gap` stays the same and the number of [inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)) in the array gets smaller. Both `gap` and the number of inversions are integers bounded below by 1 and 0 respectively, so they cannot get smaller indefinitely.

  - If `gap` was 2 or more, then it gets smaller on that iteration (note the `floor` function).
  - If `gap` was 1, then it stayed at 1, and `sorted` was set to `true` before the inner loop. `sorted` can only be set back to `false` by swapping `input[i]` and `input[i+1]` for some `i` where `input[i] > input[i+1]`. Such a swap reduces the number of inversions in the array by 1. The inner loop does not perform swaps in any other circumstances, so no swap can increase the number of inversions when `gap = 1`.
- If `sorted = true` at the end of the loop, we know that `gap = 1` because otherwise `sorted` cannot be set to `true`. Then we also know that every `input[i] <= input[i+1]` because if this were not true for some `i`, then `sorted` would have been set to `false`. Therefore, `sorted` is only true at the end of the loop when every pair of adjacent elements in the array is in order, i.e. the array is sorted.